# IndexOutOfBoundsException on setMultiChoiceItems click

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-alertdialog, indexoutofboundsexception

I am using an dialog with multiple choices items. As soon as a user clicks on an item, an item from `itemsList` wil be added to the `selectedItemsList` and of course when the user deselect a item, that item will be removed from the `selectedItemsList`.

When testing my app using [Monkey](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey.html). I am getting these errors:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3

...

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 3
```

The snippet:

```
List<Item> itemsList; // this list is populated before accessing
List<SelectedItem> selectedItemsList;

...

    dialogBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(playlists, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                selectedItemsList.add(new SelectedItem(itemsList.get(which).getId()));

            } else if (selectedItemsList.get(which) != null) {
                selectedItemsList.remove(which);
            }

        }
    });
```

I could 'solve' this by checking if `which` is less then `selectedItemsList.size()`. But to my knowledge, if this returns false; the item wil not be removed from the `selectedItemsList` but the checkbox wil be unchecked. Which causes that everything wil mix up

Comment: I guess, the Arraylist starts from 0 and the integer value of onClick starts from 1. If your onClick integer value more than the ArrayList size, then that could be throw  IndexOutOfBound Exception. Try using .get(which-1)/.remove(which-1).

Comment: @HariRam I have just tested it, the integer value of onClick start from 0.. :(

Comment: Check the size of the LIST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to overide the `equals()` methode for the `SelectedItem` class

**Updated snippet:**

```
List<Item> itemsList; // this list is populated before accessing
List<SelectedItem> selectedItemsList;

...
       dialogBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(playlists, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        selectedItemsList.add(itemsList.get(which).getSelectedItem());

                    } else if (selectedItemsList.get(which) != null) {
                        selectedPlaylists.remove(itemsList.get(which).getSelectedItem());
                    }

                }
        });
```

**SelectedItem.class**

```
    ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return (this.id.equals(((SelectedItem) o).getId()));
    }
```

**Item.class**

```
    ...

    public SelectedItem getSelectedItem() {
        return new SelectedItem(id);
    }
```

NOTE: I have left outsome code.

Answer (score 2):

The size of the list that you can select from isn't the same as the size of the list you're removing from, so instead of

```
            selectedItemsList.remove(which);
```

you need

```
            selectedItemsList.remove(selectedItemsList.getItemWithId(itemsList.get(which).getID())
```

or something similar

The `getItemWithId` won't exist though. I'm not really sure what you mean by `itemsList.getItem` and I'm assuming your `selectedItemList` and your `itemList` both hold different types. If they held the same types you could just

```
        selectedItemsList.remove(itemsList.get(which))
```

If this doesn't make sense, post your SelectedItem class and where you are creating both your lists, and I'll be able to help further.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I have left outsome code and forgot to remove itemsList.getItem. I have fixed the issue, please look at my updated question and my answer.